# What DOM element, contained in high (long) parent element is first visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In web messenger application (like Telegram), I have rendered multiple last messages (say 200) of long conversation into single parent DIV element (lets call it "space"). Each message is a DIV of variable height. Lets suppose, total space's height is 7000, so it is scrollable.

How can I detect (with minimum CPU usage) the first visible message?

The simplest/greatest idea I have so far: iterate space's children from top and stop at first msg such that:

```
msg.offsetHeight >= space.scrollTop
```

But that will eat CPU on each scroll micro-step, because `scroll` event fires every time page moved, not when scroll is done.

Ideas:

1. Do nothing on `scroll` event, but count that events.
2. Each 500ms start a function that check counter. `if (count > 0)` then `counter = 0` and do processing above; so my information about first visible element will be updated 2 times a second - good enough for my task.

But when space's height will become 40000 and number of rendered messages in "space" (parent DIV) will reach 1000, iterating so many elements does not seem good idea in terms of CPU usage and UI blocking/locking on such processing. I would build some binary interval tree allowing to find element by Y-coordinate, but dont like the idea of updating it on every insert messages at the top of "space" and overall complexity.

Also, know about `document.elementFromPoint`, but I am not sure if I know absolute coordinates of my "space" (this knowledge considered not good for now).

Comment: Modern browsers can use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to check whether elements are currently in the viewport OR become visible in the viewport. there's no need to setup a polling mechanism, you can rely on the browser to notify you.  [This example](https://codepen.io/aaronbushnell/pen/PBJLjO?editors=1111) will console log when the div scrolls into view, and log again when it leaves the view.